# Inheritable Java Class Equivalents for Path, Polygon, Area and Line in C#

Tags: c#, java, geometry

I'm trying to translate some code from Java to C# and the Java classes being implemented inherit from these classes:

```
java.awt.geom.Area
java.awt.Polygon
java.awt.geom.Path2D.Double
java.awt.geom.Line2D.Double
```

I've been researching it a bit and there seems to be a couple equivalent classes in C# in the ;System.Drawing.Drawing2d; namespace, but they are all marked as not inheritable.  Does anyone know if there are any equivalent inheritable classes to these in C#?

Comment: As far as I know, there aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the classes absolutely *need* to inherit from these types? I'd be surprised if it was terribly difficult to refactor things so that your classes have **has-a** relationships instead of **is-a** with the geometry types.
i.e.: Can you just have the geometry types as a field of your objects, and pass the field instead of the object itself as required?